# Which API Access Tokens Have an Expiration Time?

Tags: api, access-token

I know that some services using OAuth Dance have `Access Tokens that expires`,and that there are some that `by default expire,but there is a way to avoid it without refreshing them`.

**Question:**

Which of this services have an Access Token that expires, and if there is any way to avoid it just like facebook does,using a parameter for its token to not expire.

.LinkedIn

.FourSquare

.Facebook

.Twitter

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Twitter and Foursquare don't expire. You seem to already know what happens with Facebook. For LinkedIn, you can specify when asking for permissions how long you want access for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

"How long does an access token last?

We do not currently expire access tokens. Your access token will be invalid if a user explicitly rejects your application from their settings or if a Twitter admin suspends your application. If your application is suspended there will be a note on your application page saying that it has been suspended."

(It looks like Twitter has a way of doing it)